# Using $_GET variables through _remap function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having some trouble pulling important get variables out of the remap function. They're being sent in as a REST string and not URI segments because the system requires a hybrid. I am unable to use $_GET variables through the _remap function and all attempts to pull them out have failed. Any ideas? Here's the code I'm using currently to test:

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array()) {
     dump($_GET);
}
```

Due to the nature of the system, many of the pages I use rely on this remap function and are unable to use static routes. If anyone has seen this and been able to get the REST data, I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly silly silly....I had to use codeigniter's Input class.

```
$this->input->get();
```

Codeigniter handles this problem it would seem, but you can't use $_GET